# Where can i set my code Logic with React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I'm doing a reddit copy with React and Redux and I started learn react/redux recently.

So I have some practical problems while I'm developing

**Question:** Where is the best program part to solve that logics problems (reducer, action, etc)?

Problem:

I need to sort topics I got from API, by Date Created or Vote Score. I started fetching data from my api on actions file.

*actions/actions.js*:

```
        export function getForumTopics(currentCategory, orderBy)
    {
        return (dispatch) => {
            if(currentCategory === all_categories)
            {
                fetch(LOCAL_API_URL + '/posts', { 
                    headers,
                }).then(resp => resp.json())
                  .then(data => dispatch(getTopics(orderTopicBy(data, orderBy))))
            }
    }
}
```

Then, i created and import that function from utils.

utils/utils.js

```
    export function orderTopicBy(topics, orderBy) {
    switch(orderBy)
    {
        case 'vote-score':
        {
            topics = topics.sort(function(a,b) {
            if(a.voteScore > b.voteScore)
                    return 1;
                else if(a.voteScore < b.voteScore)
                    return -1;
                return 0;
            });
        }
        //topic-created
        default:
            topics = topics.sort(function(a,b) {
            if(a.timestamp > b.timestamp)
                    return -1;
                else if(a.timestamp < b.timestamp)
                    return 1;
                return 0;
            });
    }
    return topics;
}
```

So basically, if everthing works good, I get that data, sort and then dispatch an action to my reducer.

That sort part, is it ok to be on utils/utils? because I'm using more than one time, so I think that's a good approach.

And where I do that sort test? On action as I'm doing now, or I need to do on my reducer?

Comment: I think you should obtain sorted data from the server. Your local sort will be inaccurate as data is paginated and you don't have the complete data set on the client.

Comment: yep, probably. But im that case, im didnt the backend server. Im doing udacity course, so they give to me that backend part, so i need to sort on client.

Answer (score 0):

Using utils for sorting functions is a good practice, although I wouldn't writing it inside an action. I think the most reasonable place to use that sorting is inside the component right before dispatching the action.

Comment: So you mean: Create a call for action, get the return of api data. If works, do a new dispatch inside the component to the reducer?

Comment: Yes, if you’ll share the component where the action is calling from, then it would  be possible to point where exactly